# Issues in making a .sh script run on each boot with cloud-init

Tags: cloud-init

I supply the below cloud-init script through Azure portal in creating a VM. and the script never runs. appreciate if anyone can suggest what's wrong with my #cloud-config upload.

observation -

1. ubuntuVMexscript.sh is written
2. test.sh is NOT written in home directory
3. /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg doesn't show the change of [scripts-user, always] in final modules.

```
#cloud-config
package_upgrade: true
write_files:
  - owner: afshan:afshan
    path: /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/ubuntuVMexscript.sh
    permissions: '0755'
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      cat > testCat < /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/ubuntuVMexscript.sh
  - owner: afshan:afshan
    path: /home/afshan/test.sh
    permissions: '0755'
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh    
      echo "test"
cloud_final_modules:
  - rightscale_userdata
  - scripts-vendor
  - scripts-per-once
  - scripts-per-boot
  - scripts-per-instance
  - [scripts-user, always]
  - ssh-authkey-fingerprints
  - keys-to-console
  - phone-home
  - final-message
  - power-state-change
```

Comment: Can you reformat what you pasted? It is hard to understand what the config looks like based on how it is formatted.

Comment: Sorry about that, content formatted.

Answer (score 0):

`write_files` runs before any user/group creation. Does the `afshan` user exist when write_files is being run? If not, attempting to set the own on the first file will throw an exception, and the `write_files` module will exit before attempting to create the second file. You can see if this is happening by checking `/var/log/cloud-init.log` on your instance.

`/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` won't get updated by user data. It will stay as-is on disk, but your user data changes will get merged on top of it.

`scripts-user` refers to scripts written to `/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts`. You haven't written anything there, so I'm not sure the purpose of your `[scripts-user, always]` change. If you're just looking to run a script every boot, the `scripts-per-boot` module (without any changes) should be fine. Every boot, it will run what's written to `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot`

Comment: If I flip the order of writing file, ie: write to /home/afshan first. then it is successful and second write to /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/ will not be written. and this is what confuses me the most. Secondly the even if I save a script in /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot manually chmod 0777 it never runs at boot. For now I have resorted to running it with init.d